# Samsung Gallery don't work on stock android. Solution?

Tags: apk, gallery, android-12, samsung-one-ui

I really liked Samsung Gallery on my [old phone](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a10-9580.php). However, I got a [new phone](https://www.gsmarena.com/t_mobile_revvl_6-11937.php) that doesn't have One UI, but purely stock android.

Unable to find Samsung Gallery in Google play. Of course, I can download the apk and install manually, which I did, but the program immediately crashes after starting without any details.

That's why I want to ask if it can be solved somehow, please?

**UPDATE:**

Using USB debug, I managed to save the error message generated when the application crashed to a file in Windows. (Using [this tutorial](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/get-android-device-log/))

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: latch-pool-1
    Process: com.sec.android.gallery3d, PID: 23749
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.support.providers.UriInterface.unsupportedUri(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.support.providers.MediaUriGed.getRawQueryUri(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.mp.executor.SecMpQueryExecutor.getRawQueryUri(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.abstraction.query.RawQueryExecutor.getRawQueryUri(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.mp.executor.SecMpQueryExecutor.rawQuery(SecMpQueryExecutor.java:3)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.abstraction.query.RawQueryExecutor.getCursor(RawQueryExecutor.java:2)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.mp.impl.BaseImpl.getCursor(BaseImpl.java:3)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.mp.impl.PicturesImpl.getTimelineFileCursor(PicturesImpl.java:8)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.mp.impl.PicturesImpl.getTimelineFileCursor(PicturesImpl.java:1)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.mp.SecMpMethodMap.lambda$init$0(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.mp.SecMpMethodMap.n0(Unknown Source:0)
        at pa.b1.query(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.mp.SecMpCompat.query(SecMpCompat.java:2)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.ProviderMap.getSecMpCursor(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.ProviderMap.query(ProviderMap.java:3)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.dal.DbCompat.query(DbCompat.java:1)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.publisher.ListDataPublisher.publishTimelineFakeData(ListDataPublisher.java:11)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.publisher.ListDataPublisher.Y(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.module.publisher.c2.onNotify(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.support.blackboard.Blackboard.lambda$notify$6(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.support.blackboard.Blackboard.c(Unknown Source:0)
        at qd.b.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.support.utils.SimpleThreadPool.lambda$attachWatchdog$0(SimpleThreadPool.java:4)
        at com.samsung.android.gallery.support.utils.SimpleThreadPool.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at de.v9.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Is it solvable, please? I didn't quite understand the error text.

Thank you

Comment: As always when an app crashes the next step should be checking `adb logcat` to see the crash reason. Most likely the app misses a system library or extension that is only available on Samsung devices or more simple it checks the device manufacturer and crashes if it is not Samsung.

Comment: Stock apps may be coupled tightly to the vendor-specific API, so they may not work when installed on different devices without modding it (i.e. reverse engineering the app, removing the restriction, and rebuilding the app).

Comment: @Robert Hello. Thanks for the good idea. I added the error message to the question. Please take a look at it. I don't know if this is solvable.

Comment: Hello. There is no point figuring out the logs here. Exceptions are useful when source code is available. Since neither you nor do we have access to source code of Samsung Gallery app there is nothing we can do to resolve the problem. You should consider moving on to a new Gallery app.

Comment: @Firelord Hello. Yes, you are right. But, it was mentioned that it might be missing some important library that only One UI contains. That's why I added the error message. However, the main reason I started this question is because I couldn't find a suitable free alternative. And I tried at least 10 of the most used ones.